# Help with function accepting real values

Tags: functions

I'm trying to define a function accepting only real values like this:

```
f[x_Real] := x^2
f[0]
```

But it outputs

> `f[0]`

and doesn't output 0.

Is there any reason why `f[x_Real]` doesn't work? I tested `f[x_Integer]` and `f[x_Complex]` and they both seem to work.

Comment: More convenient approach would be `f[x_] /; x \[Element] Reals := x^2` or `f[x_] /; Im[x] == 0 := x^2`

Comment: That works, thank you!

Comment: `f[x_?NumericQ]` is also good to keep in mind, though that will also allow complex numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me explain what went wrong.

When you define a function `f[pattern] := ...` then this will check at every occurrence of `f[x]` if `x` matches `pattern`.

Your pattern was `x_Real` which means "match any expression whose `Head` is `Real`". In Mathematica floating point numbers have the `Head` `Real`.

```
In[1]:= Head[0]
Out[1]= Integer

In[2]:= Head[0.]
Out[2]= Real
```

However, you do not care whether or not the argument has had `Real`, rather you want it to be an element of the set `Reals`. This is what Artes suggested in the comments by using a `Condition`

```
f[x_] /; Element[x, Reals] := x^2
```

Alternatively you could also use a `PatternTest`

```
f[x_?Element[#, Reals]&] := x^2
```

Comment: `f[x_?Element[#, Reals]&] := x^2` does not work , but `f[x_/;Element[#, Reals]&] := x^2` works.

Answer (score 3):

0 without the "." is an Integer, see

```
Head @ 0
```

(* Integer *)

but

```
f[0.]
```

delivers

```
0.
```